# Emacs: DiredSort : can't sort by size

Tags: dired

Linux Mint 20.1

Emacs 26.1

Install dired+ package. Also install DiredSort from here

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSort

I try to sort by size.

```
dired-sort-size
```

[image]

But I get error on empty screen:
[image]

Error:

```
insert-directory: Listing directory failed but ‘access-file’ worked
```

Comment: For googlers: [dired-quick-sort](https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-quick-sort) worked well for me. It has a Hydra to choose the sort options: by size, extension, time, what sort of time to consider (last modification, atime, ctime…), group directories or not, in reverse order…

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem has nothing to do with [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus). I think you'll have the same problem if you don't load Dired+.

I can't speak for library `dired-sort.el`, which defines the command you're using. It may have a bug. Maybe contact the maintainer.

Emacs-Wiki page [DiredSorting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSorting) lists other libraries that offer sorting possibilities.

I use [Dired Sort Menu](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) (libraries [dired-sort-menu+.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu%2b.el) and [dired-sort-menu.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu.el)), and they work fine for sorting by file size.

You can also just customize your `dired-listing-switches` string to include the character `S` (uppercase).  Or just use `C-u` when you invoke Dired, and add `S` to the listing switches when prompted for them.